Piping email with PHP / Siteground
Host is siteground.
I have a pipe filter setup to
/home/customer/www/(mysite)/public_html/incoming.email.php
and
redirect to (alt email).
I know that the filter is being triggered because I receive the email at the alt email.
I know the script works on some level because when I execute from command line, I can see it ran in the error log.
Script:
#!/usr/bin/php -q

<?php

error_log("Email Received, Script Running");

?>

Expecting it to fill the error log with that single line but it only does it when executed via command line.

Did you read this article? Especially the last bullet point. I don't use Siteground, so I cannot test anything myself, but this is clearly missing from the things you say you've done.
